no iPadPro (2018) USB-C video output after 17.6.1 update
I have an iPadPro (2018) I’ve been using with my Dell 4k USB-C monitor almost 2 years now.
I got a new MacBookPro and decided to make this the primary USB-C device so I haven’t connected my iPadPro over USB-C video for about 3-4 weeks now.
I updated to iPadOS 17.6.1 last week and when I plug my iPadPro back into my monitor via USB-C, the monitor doesn’t register a signal.
However, the charging icon does come on so it’s getting power from the monitor. If I put a USB stick into the USB port on my monitor, it no longer comes up in the Files.app (it used to).  So therefore, the iPadPro is no longer registering the USB-C monitor as a valid USB-C device/hub (as it did before).
I’ve rebooted my iPadPro and power cycled my monitor - no video signal over USB-C and the monitor goes to sleep.
My workaround is to output over HDMI using my USB-C hub and it works just fine but prefer USB-C video as it is noticeably crisper and sharper.
Is there a new setting or permission I need to enable in iPad 17.6.1?

I would expect this to be due to a coincidence where your port on your iPad is dirty or failed and less likely that your iPad installed this update incorrectly. We would have dozens of questions if the Apple update broke this across all devices that updated to the patch (and we haven't seen that). Are you backed up and ready to try an erase all content and settings to decide if you want to restore the iPad before contacting Apple for service?

The cable could be defective (quite improbable as your iPad gets power), or maybe this is simply not the cable you used last time, and you are using instead a cable that doesn't transmit data or video, only power. If you have another USB-C cable at hand, could you try it and report back?

@bmike yes, you may be right and yes, my entire iPad is backed up to iCloud+.  Are there other ways to test USB-C video out?  I don’t have another USB-C monitor to verify this with.  The reason I do suspect it is software is Apple got cutting the USB-C video out signal when the iPad goes to sleep fixed and a regression got re-introduced in an update earlier this year and it still hadn’t gotten fixed. so from my perspective, the USB-C video stack is flakey.

@jaume tried the brand new USB-C cable Dell provided with the replacement unit (last year) I never used.  Same issue so I don’t think it’s the cable.

I try to use Thunderbolt 4 cables on iPad Pro. I don’t know how you would test things without a fairly expensive USB analyzer if you don’t have several displays, hubs and cables. Good thought trying a cable you had.

hmm - I guess if there isn’t a clever way to test USB-C video out on the iPadPro, I might have to let this one be.  I’ll probably escalate to Apple Support and give them a heads up on the bug that has already been outstanding in their system for over a year - it might be related.  but for now, my MacBookPro is happy to own and takeover USB-C video out duties- it’s more practical anyways esp w Sidecar and Universal Control! (not to take a tangent)
